# Reading parquet files in AWS Glue

Tags: amazon-web-services, parquet, aws-glue

I'm a AWS Glue newbie that is trying to read some parquet objects that I have in S3 but I fail by ClassNotFoundException. This is my attempt so far based on the minimal documentation of Glue:

```
import com.amazonaws.services.glue.GlueContext
import com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.JsonOptions
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

val gc: GlueContext = new GlueContext(sc)

val spark_session : SparkSession = gc.getSparkSession

val source = gc.getSource("s3", JsonOptions(Map("paths" -> Set("s3://path-to-parquet"))))

val parquetSource = source.withFormat("parquet")

parquetSource.getDynamicFrame().show(1)
```

And the exception:

```
   18/06/11 13:39:11 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 6.0 (TID 266, ip-172-31-8-179.eu-west-1.compute.internal, executor 16): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to load format with name parquet
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.ClassUtils$.loadByFullName(ClassUtils.scala:28)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.ClassUtils$.getClassByName(ClassUtils.scala:43)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.ClassUtils$.newInstanceByName(ClassUtils.scala:54)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.readers.DynamicRecordStreamReader$.apply(DynamicRecordReader.scala:187)
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: parquet
    at org.apache.spark.repl.ExecutorClassLoader.findClass(ExecutorClassLoader.scala:82)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.ClassUtils$$anonfun$1.apply(ClassUtils.scala:25)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.ClassUtils$$anonfun$1.apply(ClassUtils.scala:25)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.ClassUtils$.loadByFullName(ClassUtils.scala:25)
    ... 28 more
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I solved the issue. I had specified the wrong connectionType for 'getSource': it should be "parquet" and not "s3":

```
import com.amazonaws.services.glue.GlueContext
import com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.JsonOptions
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

val gc: GlueContext = new GlueContext(sc)

val spark_session : SparkSession = gc.getSparkSession

val source = gc.getSource("parquet", JsonOptions(Map("paths" -> Set("s3://path-to-parquet"))))

source.getDynamicFrame().show(1)
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-connect.html#aws-glue-programming-etl-connect-parquet

Hopefully this helps somebody!

Comment: This is now an answered question, so click the green checkmark (marking your own answer as correct); this way people will know the question has an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I am a bit late to answer this but the answer to this query has become straightforward now.

To read your parquet file, you need to import the libraries and start the spark session correctly and you should know the correct path of the `parquet` file in S3.

Here is a dummy code. Use it for reference:

```py
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job

sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
```

**First way [Detailed way]**

```py
s3_path= "s3://aws-glue-111122223333-...."
dynamic_frame= glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    connection_type = "s3",
    connection_options= {"paths":[s3_path]},
    format = "parquet")

#the dynamic frame can be converted to pyspark dataFrame to be viewed as a tabular format.
spark_df = dynamic_frame.toDF()
spark_df.show()
```

**Second way [shortcut way]**

```py
spark_dataframe = spark.read.parquet(s3_path)
spark_dataframe.show()
```

**Personally**, I find the detailed way more beautiful, especially for beginners. It will make you understand what you're doing easily.
You can read more about it in the [AWS official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-format-parquet-home.html)

I am recommending detailed way because **similar lines of code are needed** for importing data from your *glue data catalog*. So use the shortcut way when you get used to the development environment.

```py
# to import data from Glue data catalog, code goes along the lines of....
dyf = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(
      database='database_name', 
      table_name='table_name',
      transformation_ctx= 'dyf',
      catalog_id = "111122223333")
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Your 'first way' and 'second way' are not quite equivalent. The latter returns a spark `dataframe`, not a `dynamic_frame`. But thanks for the Python example

Comment: @selle, late reply. Thanks for pointing it out. I had already updated the answer.